# How to retry in the same line after exception?

Tags: python, exception

I have the following code:

```
def my_function:
    #operation 1
    #operation 2
    ...
    #operation 99
    #operation 100

def handle_exception:
    #handle exception
```

Now, during any part of executing my_function an exception might occur. If it does, I want to handle it by calling handle_exception method. And then go back to my_function and retry the same operation that caused the exception. If it works this time, continue with the code. The exceptions might happen in random places in the code and I don't want to retry whole my_function.

So for example. I am executing my_function. Operation 1 worked correctly. During operation 2 there was an exception. I handle the exception and then try operation 2 again. It works this time so I continue with operations.

Is this possible in Python?

Comment: Make a list of functions and call each inside a try/except block.

Comment: This can be done but does it make sense? If an exception occurs, why might it not reoccur if you run the same code again?

Comment: @Vlad maybe the `handle_exception` function will solve what caused the exception, so it makes sense trying to rerun the code.

Comment: List of functions is not really something I would like as there would be far too many of them.
The exceptions i talk about are connection errors and usually it's enough to rerun.

Comment: Well, it's up to you. Either make a list of functions or add exception handling and a loop to each call site you have now.

Comment: @Artkor If the connection errors you refer to are related to *requests* or *urllib* functionality you should probably research the retry mechanisms that are available in those modules

Comment: Does the same exception handler really apply to every operation? Start explicit: handle exception for each operation separately, then go back and refactor if it makes sense to do so.

Answer (score -2):

**I would do this:**

```
def my_function(start = 0):

    def operation1():
        ...
    def operation2():
        ...
    oper = [operation1, operation2]
   
    for index in range(start, len(oper)):
        try:
            oper[index]()
        except:
            handle_exception(index)
            break
def handle_exception(index):
    #handle exception
    my_function(index)
```

**Of course you need the function `handle_exception` to solve the problem, otherwise it will lead to infinite recursion**

Here is an example to understand how the code works:

```
def my_function(start = 0):

def operation1():
    global i
    print(i[2])
def operation2():
    print(2)
oper = [operation1, operation2]

for index in range(start, len(oper)):
    try:
        oper[index]()
    except:
        handle_exception(index)
        break
def handle_exception(index):
    global i
    i = ["a", "b", "c"]
    my_function(index)

i = ["a", "b"]
my_function()
```

Note that the function `handle_exception` fixes the i list, so that there will not be an `index error`.

Comment: I see you have made a list of functions, but they are not retried if there is an exception.

Comment: @quamrana They are. `handle_exception()` calles them from index position

Comment: This will cause recursion if any exception occurs

Comment: and retry functions out of order.

Comment: Mistake. It calls the function from the index location, from the location it failed.

Comment: and added an example

Comment: @chepner See the content of the question